# Python MySQL not updating field or returning error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have the following code:

```
def post(self):
    data = UserActivation.parser.parse_args()

    check = UserConfirm.check_token(data['email'],data['token'])
    activate_user = UserConfirm.activate_user(data['email'])


    if check == False:
        return {"message": "Invalid Token or Email Address"}, 400
    else:
        if activate_user:
            return {"message": "Your account is now active"}, 201
        else:
            return {"message": "Error Activating Account"}, 500
```

that gets passed into `UserConfirm` class in the user models:

```
def activate_user(email):
        query_users = "UPDATE users SET activated=1 WHERE email=%s"
        cursor.execute(query_users, (email,))
```

For some reason the code doesn't fail nor does it update the database. I tried to put in some error handling as follows just to see what was going on:

```
        try:
            email = data['email']
            query_users = "UPDATE users SET activated=1 WHERE email=%s"
            cursor.execute(query_users, (email,))
            return {"message": "done"}, 201
            conn.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error as e:
            error=e.args[0], e.args[1]
            return {"message": error}, 500
```

I'm using Postman to send the values to the end point and know that it is working properly because the `check_token()` function works just fine. The strange thing is that the query doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't update the DB. In PhpMyAdmin, I can write out the SQL query as above without any issues.

Also, if I deliberately put in the wrong value, it still returns without errors.

**EDIT** I've found the solution to be having to use `conn.close()`

Comment: Maybe the transaction has not been committed? Try adding database_connection.commit() after the cursor.execute, just to find out if that's the case. That's not the solution though, just the diagnostics.

Comment: doesn't change anything. very strange error. I don't have this issue with insert or select queries

Answer (score 0):

It's a wild guess, but probably You need to commit Your changes, something, like this (assuming `conn` is object returned by `MySQLdb.connect()`):

```
    try:
        email = data['email']
        query_users = "UPDATE users SET activated=1 WHERE email=%s"
        cursor.execute(query_users, (email,))
        conn.commit()
        return {"message": "done"}, 201
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        error=e.args[0], e.args[1]
        return {"message": error}, 500
```

Comment: I've tried it that way already, sorry I forgot to put that in my edit. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so strangely enough I tried using `conn.close()` and it worked? Not sure if Update queries keep the connection open without committing until it's been closed - but it seems to have worked for me. I only thought of this because MySQL kept timing out when using PhpMyadmin. Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.